# Online Model Theory Classes

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, online-resources

Since "model theory" is kind of too general naming, I have encountered with lots of irrelevant results (like mathematical modelling etc.) when I searched for some videos on the special mathematical logic branch "model theory".

So, do you know/have you ever seen any online lecture videos on model theory? Any relevant answer will be appreciated...

Comment: @Potato I am just looking for some video lectures. No need for textbooks or notes as I have many of them.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/user/pstinchcombe?feature=watch

Comment: I have the same situation. Maybe you can found something helpful in mathseminars.org

Answer (score 1):

If you are french fluent, here are the lecture notes of Tuna Altinel course :

http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~altinel/Master/m11415.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JwQmwkrtoA&list=PLJmfLfPx1Oef_nObIEOUfZDeCnX46ok78), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5HwOJvMNwg&list=PL9kd4mpdvWcCQ97cjtjaK0Y_sKAJSvway), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fiLpquKWaGY&list=PLcwjc2OQcM4vUDLb7_0GDJki0IzY9y8bH) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taUMcGbO4Oo&list=PLr9iBVA7rHulYFChhZbox8gQDxFdFJo8g) on Youtube.